# @Noncacheable annotation not working properly in eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I've base entity class named Person, it has Manager field, this field implements @ManyToOne relationship sharing the same base table (person). In the code, we've explicitly want this relationship to not be cached, hence we decalred it with @Noncacheable annotation,
so we when we try to fetch person related record, expectation is to fetch manager info from datasource not from cache, but in the response we'll see the manager returns empty, we observed behaviour that the manager field is also getting L2 cached. As a workaround solution, we add annotation as @Cache(alwaysrefresh=true) , Post that manager field returns value.

Can someone pls explain above behaviour and the underhood working mechanism of @Noncacheable annotation.

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_noncacheable.htm

Comment: Thank you for the response, Yeah, we've used in same way as in documentation, but we havent explicitly mentioned @cache annotation @Cache(
  isolation=CacheIsolationType.PROTECTED
), Had configuration in persistence.xml to include entity class by default to L2 cache. can you please let me know, whether isolation parameters needs to be defined explicitly as in documentation.

Comment: The NonCacheable annotation sounds like you have it on the relationship. That just means that a person's manager is not cached within the person object. When you access that person's manager, it'll fetch like any lazy relationship. Where it fetches the manager instance from though depends on the Manager class' cache settings. If that instance is in the cache and it is cacheable, that is what is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response , In this case Manager is field name , its instance of person class, (i.e, @Noncacheable Person manager;), as both Person and Manager objects are referring same class , will it requires any additional changes

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. Any fetch of Person will use the cacheable settings defined for the Person class. Non-cacheable refers to the reference (manager reference) not to instances of the class itself. Your manager is just a person, and cached like any other based on the class settings (in the L2 cache). If you don't want that, you'll have to make changes. Turn logging to finest and test it out with different settings - and inspect your object to see that manager isn't there or populated until it is first accessed by the app.